# Why isn't this $.getJSON 's callback function being executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is the script that attempts to get the json file:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    //////////////////////HEADLINE NEWS JSON SERVER START///////////////////////////
    var container = $("#headlineNews"); //cache the element
    console.log("First Log message is here!")
    $.getJSON("/JsonControl/Headline_News.json", function(jsonObj) {
        console.log("Second Log message is here!")
        var val = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.news.length; ++i) {
            val += "<div id='newsHeading'>" 
                + jsonObj.news[i].heading 
                + "</div><br/><div id='newsSummary'>" 
                + jsonObj.news[i].summary 
                + "</div><br/>";

            if (jsonObj.news[i].linkText != "" && jsonObj.news[i].linkPath != "") {
                val += "<a href='" + jsonObj.news[i].linkPath + "'>" + jsonObj.news[i].linkText + "</a><br/><br/>";
            }

            val += "<div class='entryDivider'>____________________________________________________</div>";
        }

        container.html(val);
    });

    //////////////////////HEADLINE NEWS JSON SERVER END/////////////////////////////
});​
```

Here is the json file itself:

```
{
    "news": [
        {
        "heading": "Bulky Item Pick-Up to Begin May 4th, 2012 for Residential Utility Account Holders.",
        "summary": "Click on the link below for more details.",
        "linkText": "Bulky Item Pick-Up",
        "linkPath": "/Displayable Files/City_Bulk_Pick_Up_for_e_mailing.pdf"},
    {
        "heading": "NOW OPEN!",
        "summary": "OKMULGEE RECYCLING CENTER<br/>301 E. 3rd Street<br/>(Corner of E. 3rd St. and N. Muskogee Ave.).",
        "linkText": "WHAT TO AND WHAT NOT TO RECYCLE",
        "linkPath": "/Displayable Files/Recycling_Items.pdf"}
    ]
}​

//To omit any of these options, simply leave them blank (i.e., "linkText":"").
```

I have attempted to use console.log, but only the first one executes and the second one doesn't, so I know the contents of the $.getJSON branch isn't getting executed at all (meaning the $.getJSON statement is a fail, if I understand it correctly).  However absolutely no script errors occur.

Also, the server IS set up to serve json files, as another tester site has executed an external json file just fine.

It feels like the path is wrong somehow, but I'm not getting a 404, and I've rechecked this path to make sure that it is syntactically correct at least a dozen times.

How can the $.getJSON command fail if the path to the file is correct, the syntax of the json file is correct, and the server definitely is configured to serve up json files (e.g., application/json MIME type is set)? Is there anything else it could possibly be or would the second console.log not execute if the rest of the branch doesn't?

-------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

I have edited my post to reflect comments that I (erroneously) had in my json file.

Comment: If you visit `yourdomain.com/JsonControl/Headline_News.json` in your browser, do you see the JSON?

Comment: Yes I see the text only json file

Comment: Try to use any inspect tool to check whether there is a request of that json.

Comment: I am showing a request (cached) for the json file, however I think it is because I visited the site in my browser. No other requests are showing.

Comment: $.getJSON returns a promise. Have you tried to add a .fail() callback and inspect any feedback returned there.  $.getJSON("/JsonControl/Headline_News.json", function() { ... }).fail(function() {console.dir({fail:arguments});});

Comment: @Alexander Your point about 'pasting as they are' is very much taken.

Comment: @Whoever clarified that I had invalid comments in my json file should post an answer so that I can accept and help future visitors... Unless, this post should be deleted or closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript comments (nor any other) aren't legal in JSON syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $.ajax since it allows you to specify a success, error, and complete (finally) callback.  Perhaps your callback isn't being called because it's a success callback and the request is returning an error.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  type: 'POST',
  data: jsonData
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  },
  error: function(request, status, error) {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: $.getJSON is a promise as well, and as such allows you to use the then/fail/done/error/success/complete callbacks as well. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @Chifriend This seems helpful, I will have to check that out.

Comment: He should use deferred objects

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if you get json returned in the console.

```
$.getJSON("/JsonControl/Headline_News.json", function(jsonObj) {
   console.log(jsonObj);
});
```

Comment: While that's not the answer, it is very helpful. I was looking for something that could at least tell me more about what I did wrong, but I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: Since I took comments out, yes. I assumed that javascript comments would be legal in json. I was dead wrong.  It is working now.

Comment: I suggest you to go to jsonlint.com for the json validation. Its a great online tool for json data to validate and it perfectly structures.

Comment: @Jai I definitely will, now that I know it exists. I just learned about it in this post.

Comment: @Jai Also, yeah, that restructuring thing is amazing. Especially considering (and I don't know if it is this way for most json files in general, but...) the fact that I am using this so that other less technical savvy individuals will be able to edit parts of our website without having to edit several different files, or mess with html/css/etc.  That restructuring pretty much formats it exactly like I want it!